# Kendo UI for Angular combobox, filtering with two letters occasionally returns empty results

Tags: combobox, filtering, kendo-ui-angular2

I did notice some weird behavior when filtering inside a combobox.
Entering a single letter works wine and narrows results, but here is what happens if I type t, and then tr, tra. What could be causing that?

[image: Entered t]

[image: Empty list after entering tr]

[image: Expected results again after entering tra]

Using backspace from tra to tr displays correct result.
Did notice that behavior in some other comboboxes on current screen.
Yes this is using Kendo-UI for Angular Combobox.

```
<form-combobox [data]="pickListData.activityTypes"
                             valueField="code"
                             textField="codeDescription"
                             [loading]="pickListDataLoading$ | async"
                             [defaultSelected]="0"
                             [filterable]="true"
                             [ngrxFormControlState]="formState.controls.activityType"></form-combobox>
```

Comment: Where is the <form-combobox> coming from? Library, component etc.

Answer (score 1):

By using `[filterable]="true"` you are stating that the list should be filterable. But you actually have to write a function like `(filterChange)="handleFilter($event)"` where you filter the data from the list based on the typed input.

If you want the kendo combobox to take care of filtering then you can simply use [kendoDropDownFilter] to which you can provide settings like if you want the search to be case sensitive and others.
Ref- https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/dropdowns/combobox/filtering/